# checkout as guest redirects back to product page

Tags: checkout, guest-checkout

I have just moved a new Magento website onto it's production server. The website seems to work fine, however after clicking 'proceed to checkout', when you click on 'checkout as guest' and then complete your details, you are then sent back to the product page. Could this be a cache problem? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug the problem:

- Enable website logs from **System > Configuration > Advanced (Developer) > Log settings**.
- Delete log files (if any) from **`/var/log`** folder of your magento installation.
- Add product to cart and checkout as guest until you are redirected back to product page.
- Now go to **`/var/log`** folder of magento installation and check log files generated.

I hope you will find some clue from log flies.

Comment: Thanks,
The log file gives the following:

2016-07-26T07:48:09+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'  in /var/www/vhosts/peachtest.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 67

2016-07-26T07:48:09+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_MODE_ECB - assumed 'MCRYPT_MODE_ECB'  in /var/www/vhosts/peachtest.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 71

Any ideas what may cause this? I have checked on the webserver and the php mcrypt module is installed.

Comment: Open terrminal and run this command:sudo php5enmod mcrypt

Comment: Thank you both.
The problem is now solved. Running the command gave me an 'mcrypt not installed' error. On investigation the wrong php handler was selected on the VPS. I changed this to 5.6.23 and this now works. Thanks again.